# Prove that for fixed $c$ there exits $d$ such that polynomials $p_ 1(x,y)-cq_1(x,y) $and $p_2(x,y)-dq_2(x,y)$ are coprime

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, coprime

Let
$$
f(x,y)=p_1(x,y)-cq_1(x,y),\\
g(x,y)=p_2(x,y)-dq_2(x,y),
$$
be polynomials, where $c,d\in\left(0,1\right)$. Coefficient $x,y$ of polynomials represent probabilities, so $x,y\in\left<0,1\right>$. Polynomials $p_1(x,y)$ and $q_1(x,y)$ are coprime. Also polynomials $p_2(x,y)$ and $q_2(x,y)$ are coprime. How to prove that for fixed $c\in\left(0,1\right)$ there are finite number of $d\in\left(0,1\right)$ such that polynomials $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are not coprime?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: From what type of ring are the polynomial coef's, and what are $c$ and $d$, coef's or poly's? Is the question to prove that there is at least one $d$ *only* by proving there are finite many... or, rather, by any method?

Comment: @ Bill Dubuque Sorry, I am going to edit my question.